# How to assign typescript types to this type of array of object

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript. I came across a problem to assign types to an array of object.

This is a snippet suggestion of typescript.

How to assign typescript types to this type of array of object.

```
const something: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    dob: Date;
    phone: string;
    address: {
        street: string;
        suite: string;
        city: string;
        zipcode: string;
        geo: {
            lat: string;
            lng: string;
        };
    };
    website: string;
    company: {
        ...;
    };
}[][]
```

And what to call this type of array of object.

Comment: Note that this is an array *of arrays* of objects

Comment: Also, you don't assign a type to a variable, you declare it to be of a specific type. You have already declared the variable something to be of the type you defined. Now you need to assign it a value that matches the type you've given it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define interfaces beginning at the leaves of the data type tree and nest them in upper levels of the tree. In the end of this algorithm, you will have a type that aggregates all your internal data types.

For example, define,

```
interface Geo {
    lat: string;
    lon: string;
}
```

Then the interface for address can be written as:

```
interface Address {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: Geo;
};
```

And so on.

In the root of the data type tree, you will have an interface like:

```
interface Person{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    dob: Date;
    phone: string;
    address: Address;
    website: string;
    company: Company;
}
```

And you can declare your variable to be of type `Person[][]`.